# Website loads from many locations except one, not sure how to troubleshoot

Tags: asp.net, connectivity

I have a website hosted at webhost4life.com. It works fine when I load up the website from various locations (home, coffee shop, library, etc). But **from my friend's house it will NOT load**. It just looks like it's sitting there thinking and the website might load a few images here and there but that's. The full page doesn't load and most of the time nothing loads.

This is a c# asp.net website. **My question is, how do i go about troubleshooting to find out what is wrong?**

Right now I do not really know where to start. These are the things I have tried:

- static page - i uploaded a **static html page and that loads up fine**!
- fiddler - i track the session in fiddler and get nothing back. but when i try the static page i get normal results and it's working fine.
- tracert www.mydomain.com - this looks fine, i get similar results with www.yahoo.com
- telnet www.mydomain.com 80 - i do this to ping port 80 of the website. if i type "get" and hit enter i see a "Bad request" message but i see the same message for other websites and they work fine from here
- ftp - ftp works fast and is fine

So at this point, I know that my asp.net parts of the website **doesn't seem to work but only from this one location**. It works fine from everywhere else I have tried. But static pages DO work just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest that you capture your request headers (with Fiddler or Wireshark) and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the telnet 'get' and actually request a page that is having problems.   It could be that you are referencing elements in your application that your friend's computer is having trouble connecting to.  If you get back all the mark up of the page, then it's one of the items that the page is referencing that is causing the problem.  If the page renders incompletely, then your site may be having problems or the might be a network issue between your friend's house and your site.  Since your application loads up from other locations I'd suspect that your friend's computer or network has the problem rather than your site.  Your site shouldn't care where the request is coming from.